# Querystring display details

Tags: asp.net, linq, request.querystring

I got this tblDocument table which has a one to many relationship to a couple of other tables. I have created this querystring that displays the content of the document. In this soulution i only display the DocPerson id. What im trying to do is to display the name of the person which is located in the tblPerson table. Can someone help me?

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string strId = Request.QueryString["id"];
        int id;
        if (int.TryParse(strId, out id))
        {
            var db = new MyModelContext();
            var p = db.tblDocuments.SingleOrDefault(x => x.DocId == id);
            if (p != null)
            {

                lblCaseNr.Text = p.DocNr;
                lblPerson.Text = p.DocPerson.ToString();
                lblCourt.Text = p.DocCourt.ToString();
                lblYear.Text = p.Docyear.ToString();
                lblResume.Text = p.DocResume;
                lblResult.Text = p.DocResult;
                lblLaw.Text = p.DocLaw.ToString();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code (I am already seeing a DocPerson?)? Is it throwing an error? Also, you don't need to do the ToString() anymore if the property is already a string.

Comment: The DocPerson is a int and is the ID of the Person. So the ToString() is necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `LINQ` expression, try the following:

```
var q = from d in db.tblDocuments join p in db.tblPerson 
          on d.DocId equals p.DocId
          where d.DocId == id
          select new {d.DocId, p.DocPerson}
```

If you need to access other fields, simply add them to your `select new` clause.

Comment: where do you want the linq expression added?

Comment: Replace your current `LINQ` expression with this one.  This will give you an anonymous type.  In order to access the properties, you can loop through with a `foreach` statement.  Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) for more info.